# Plot a time series graph with dates on the X and Y axis

Tags: r

I am using R to reproduce the following graph:[image: Image of a line graph with date and month on the Y axis and the year on the X axis. All points on the graph are connected by a single line.]

So I used the following data frame

```
Doy = as.data.frame(list( Year=Year, M_Day =M_Day, Mon_day = Mon_day))
```

where Year, M_Day and Mon_day are as below

```
Year = c(1960, 1961,
  1962,
  1963,
  1964,
  1965,
  1966,
  1967,
  1968,
  1969,
  1970,
  1971,
  1972,
  1973,
  1974,
  1975,
  1976,
  1977,
  1978,
  1979
)

M_Day = c("05-14",
  "05-05",
  "05-15",
  "05-31",
  "05-01",
  "05-01",
  "05-01",
  "05-01",
  "05-01",
  "05-01",
  "05-16",
  "05-14",
  "05-09",
  "05-22",
  "05-18",
  "06-17",
  "05-03",
  "05-06",
  "05-01",
  "05-03")

Mon_day = c("May-14",
  "May-05",
  "May-15",
  "May-31",
  "May-01",
  "May-01",
  "May-01",
  "May-01",
  "May-01",
  "May-01",
  "May-16",
  "May-14",
  "May-09",
  "May-22",
  "May-18",
  "Jun-17",
  "May-03",
  "May-06",
  "May-01",
  "May-03")
```

and the following two commands from ggplot2

```
ggplot( Doy) + geom_line( aes( x=Year, y = M_Day)) + geom_point(aes( x=Year, y = M_Day)) 

ggplot( Doy) + geom_line( aes( x=Year, y = Mon_day)) + geom_point(aes( x=Year, y = Mon_day))
```

which gives me the following
[image: Image of two graphs both of which have the date and month on the Y axis and the year on the X axis. Only the points with the same Y value are connected so there are multiple lines on the graph and some points aren't connected by a line at all.]

which is not similar to the first graph.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dates to date format using `as.Date(M_Day, format="%m-%d")` an specify the desired output format of the date in the scale:

```
Year <- 1960:1979

M_Day <- as.Date(x=c("05-14", "05-05", "05-15", "05-31", "05-01", "05-01", "05-01", "05-01", "05-01", "05-01", "05-16", "05-14", "05-09", "05-22", "05-18", "06-17", "05-03", "05-06", "05-01", "05-03"),
                format="%m-%d")

Doy <- data.frame(Year=Year, M_Day=M_Day)

ggplot(Doy) + geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=M_Day), col="darkblue") + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Year, y=M_Day), col="darkred") + 
  scale_y_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%d %b")
```

Comment: Thanks very much mzuba, this is exactly what I needed :) :).